# Convert single quotes to double quotes for Dictionary key/value pair

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionory with key value pair in single inverted commas as follows:

```
filename = 'sub-310621_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_bold.nii.gz'
intended_for ={"IntendedFor", filename}
```

AS i am want to write this dictionary to a json file i have to have filename in between two inverted commas eg: `"sub-310621_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_bold.nii.gz"`

SO the output should look like:

```
intended_for ={"IntendedFor", "sub-310621_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_bold.nii.gz"}
```

This output will be written in to test.json file which should look like:

```
{
    "IntendedFor": "sub-310621_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_bold.nii.gz"
}
```

How can i do this in python ?

Comment: please edit your question to have the not-working code for outputting json, what the output is, and what you expected.

Comment: you can use `\"` to add inverted commas. for instance `filename = '\"sub-310621_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_bold.nii.gz\"'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than trying to build the JSON string yourself you should use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) module to do the encoding.

The `json.dumps()` method takes an object such as a dictionary with key value pairs and converts it into a JSON compliant string which can then be written to a file.

Instead of a dictionary, you created a set by using a comma `,` instead of a colon `:`

```
intended_for = {"IntendedFor", filename}
```

The correct code for your input would be

```
filename = 'sub-310621_task-EMOTION_acq-LR_bold.nii.gz'
intended_for ={"IntendedFor": filename}
```

Then you can encode

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps(intended_for)
```

Answer (score 6):

The apostrophes or quotation marks on the ends of a string literal are not included in the string - `'asdf'` and `"asdf"` represent identical strings. Neither the key nor the value in your dict actually include the character `'` or `"`, so you don't need to perform a conversion.

When you dump the dict to JSON, your JSON dumper will automatically surround strings with `"` characters, among other necessary escaping. For example, if you're using the `json` module, you can just do

```
json_string = json.dumps(intended_for)
```

to produce a correctly-formatted JSON string. (If this does not work, you have some other bug you're not showing us.)